# I am checking the login process in fragment class so How to close the MainActivity When i move to the home after successfull login

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

```
package com.example.login;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static Sessions session;
    public static EditText userNameFiled;
    public static EditText passwordFiled;
    public static Button loginBtn;
    String status;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        session = new Sessions(getApplicationContext());
        //status=session.PrefloginCheck();

        if (session.PrefloginCheck()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User Login Status From Main Activity: " + session.PrefloginCheck(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements
            View.OnClickListener {


        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            userNameFiled = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
            passwordFiled = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.password);
            loginBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
            loginBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            session.createLoginSession("login", "true");
            session.createLoginSession("name", "uday");
            session.createLoginSession("email", "********@gmail.com");
            Intent i = new Intent(this.getActivity(), Home.class);
            startActivity(i);

            /*
             * When i triggered the login button i want to kill the login activity
             * */
            //finish();
        }
    }

}
```

**strong text**

I am checking the login process in fragment class so 
How to close the MainActivity When i move to the home after successfull login.
I am checking the login process in fragment class so 
How to close the MainActivity When i move to the home after successfull login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to the Fragment's current Activity with [`getActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29).

So you can use `getActivity().finish()`;

Comment: Thanks for your help ,you saved my time by gaven your answer ,and it's working grate